# Connections going into close_wait

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, glassfish, httpclient

Since so many days we are facing the problem of close_wait connection..My doubt was that not all the connections with that particular server are going into close wait.If it would have been problem with the code then this problem should be with every connection I am making with the server.Destination server is apache server and source server is glassfish . I have also added header for closing connection according to this article.http://www.michaelprivat.com/?p=63 But no luck I am posting code which  I have used for making connection with the target server .Is there any problem while making connection?

```
public String Consumer(String userId, String Type) throws IOException {
                                      CloseableHttpClient hc = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
                          String response = null;
                        ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
                     HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://IP and port of th target server/PolicyService.php"); 
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userId));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type", Type));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", Token));



            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            postMethod.addHeader("Connection", "close");
            response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);

            return response;


        } catch (HttpResponseException g) {
             logger.error("Exception occurred of type: " , g);
            return "";

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             logger.error("Exception occurred of type: " , e);
            return "";


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred of type: " , e);
            return "";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred of type: " , e);
            return "";
        }
        finally{
        hc.close();
        }
    }
```

everytime  I have to restart server to flush this connections .Any sugestions?